# AlertDialog with ListView inside causing an issue

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, listviewitem, flutter-listview

I have an alert dialog with a list inside.
For some weird reason, I am getting a an error because of a size property

```
var jobTypes = [
    {"Job type": jobTypeHm, "Active": true},
    {"Job type": jobTypeLs, "Active": false},
    {"Job type": jobTypePm, "Active": false},
    {"Job type": jobTypeRm, "Active": false},
    {"Job type": jobTypeRf, "Active": false},
    {"Job type": jobTypeEl, "Active": false},
  ];

  Future _displayJobTypeAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: 300,   
              child: AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
                content: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: jobTypes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('${jobTypes[index]["Job type"]}'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Restarted application in 534ms.
D/EGL_emulation(20775): app_time_stats: avg=1214.46ms min=22.72ms max=3597.70ms count=3
W/DynamiteModule(20775): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(20775): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(20775): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/TrafficStats(20775): tagSocket(100) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/EGL_emulation(20775): app_time_stats: avg=375.60ms min=9.08ms max=1987.43ms count=6
D/EGL_emulation(20775): app_time_stats: avg=81.23ms min=13.30ms max=891.21ms count=14

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.

If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, consider a RenderShrinkWrappingViewport render object (ShrinkWrappingViewport widget), which achieves that effect without implementing the intrinsic dimension API.

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderViewportBase.debugThrowIfNotCheckingIntrinsics.<anonymous closure>
#1      RenderViewportBase.debugThrowIfNotCheckingIntrinsics
#2      RenderViewportBase.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#3      RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#5      RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#6      RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#8      RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#9      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#10     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#11     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#13     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#14     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#15     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#16     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#18     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#19     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#20     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#21     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#23     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#24     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#25     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#26     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#28     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#29     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#30     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#31     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#33     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#34     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#35     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#36     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#38     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#39     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#40     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#41     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#43     RenderCustomPaint.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#44     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#45     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#46     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#47     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#49     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#50     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#51     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#52     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#53     RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#54     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#55     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#56     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#57     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#58     RenderPadding.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#59     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#60     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#61     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#62     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#63     RenderFlex.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth.<anonymous closure>
#64     RenderFlex._getIntrinsicSize
#65     RenderFlex.computeMaxIntrinsicWidth
#66     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension.<anonymous closure>
#67     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:527:23)
#68     RenderBox._computeIntrinsicDimension
#69     RenderBox.getMaxIntrinsicWidth
#70     RenderIntrinsicWidth._computeSize
#71     RenderIntrinsicWidth.performLayout
#72     RenderObject.layout
#73     RenderBox.layout
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#75     RenderObject.layout
#76     RenderBox.layout
#77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#78     RenderObject.layout
#79     RenderBox.layout
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#81     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#82     RenderObject.layout
#83     RenderBox.layout
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#85     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#86     RenderObject.layout
#87     RenderBox.layout
#88     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
#89     RenderObject.layout
#90     RenderBox.layout
#91     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout
#92     RenderObject.layout
#93     RenderBox.layout
#94     RenderPadding.performLayout
#95     RenderObject.layout
#96     RenderBox.layout
#97     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
#98     RenderObject.layout
#99     RenderBox.layout
#100    RenderPadding.performLayout
#101    RenderObject.layout
#102    RenderBox.layout
#103    RenderPadding.performLayout
#104    RenderObject.layout
#105    RenderBox.layout
#106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#107    RenderObject.layout
#108    RenderBox.layout
#109    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#110    RenderObject.layout
#111    RenderBox.layout
#112    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#113    RenderObject.layout
#114    RenderBox.layout
#115    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#116    RenderObject.layout
#117    RenderBox.layout
#118    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#119    RenderObject.layout
#120    RenderBox.layout
#121    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#122    RenderObject.layout
#123    RenderBox.layout
#124    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#125    RenderObject.layout
#126    RenderBox.layout
#127    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#128    RenderOffstage.performLayout
#129    RenderObject.layout
#130    RenderBox.layout
#131    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#132    RenderObject.layout
#133    RenderBox.layout
#134    _RenderTheatre.performLayout
#135    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
#136    PipelineOwner.flushLayout
#137    RendererBinding.drawFrame
#138    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#139    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#140    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#141    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#142    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#143    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#144    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#145    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderIntrinsicWidth#c9923 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderIntrinsicWidth#c9923 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=312.7, 0.0<=h<=711.3)
    size: MISSING
    stepWidth: null
    stepHeight: null
    child: RenderFlex#66394 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: <none>
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        direction: vertical
        mainAxisAlignment: start
        mainAxisSize: min
        crossAxisAlignment: stretch
        verticalDirection: down
        child 1: RenderPadding#a35af NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            padding: EdgeInsets(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 0.0)
            textDirection: ltr
            child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#5e60b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
                constraints: MISSING
                semantic boundary
                size: MISSING
                child: RenderParagraph#fac88 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    textAlign: start
                    textDirection: ltr
                    softWrap: wrapping at box width
                    overflow: clip
                    locale: en_US
                    maxLines: unlimited
        child 2: RenderPadding#263c7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.loose
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            padding: EdgeInsets(24.0, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0)
            textDirection: ltr
            child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#99975 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
                constraints: MISSING
                semantic boundary
                size: MISSING
                child: RenderRepaintBoundary#51add NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    needs compositing
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIntrinsicWidth#c9923 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b6791 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderInkFeatures#484c6 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#4c909 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#a87b9 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 361 pos 12: 'child!.hasSize': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#a87b9 relayoutBoundary=up2
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I know I can hardcopy the buttons on the alert and it would work, but thats a terrible approach.
is there a better way to do this or should I just hard copy these values?

Comment: Can you try to assign width as well to the Sizedbox?

Comment: still no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your ListView inside SizedBox or Container and give it to specific heifgt and width, add shrinkWrap: true, inside ListView.builder()